# Why the jQuery AJAX. Return value is undefined?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

A weird thing is happening when I execute a function that "alerts" data from a json. If I specify, like `alert(data.name);`, the "Alert" returns "Undefined", but if I just put `alert(data);`, it returns the object like `{"id":"1","name":"Erluan"}`

This is the function that receives an id to search in the database

```
function receiveUser(val){
            $.ajax({
               type:"POST",
               url:"../json/userperm/userGrid.php",
               data: 'iduser='+val,
               datatype:"json",
               success: function(data, string, jqXHR){
                    alert(data.name);
               }
            });
}
```

And this is the userGrid.php

```
<?php
include('../../config.php');

$user = mysql_query("SELECT * from hospital_".$_SESSION['template'].".users where id = ".$_POST['iduser']." order by name");

$results = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($user))
{
   $results[] = array(
      'id' => $row['id'],
      'name' => $row['name']
   );
}

$json = json_encode($results);

echo $json;
?>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Since the return datatype is json the OP should not have to use JSON.parse @JonathanNewton

Comment: $results is array of array...after json_encode it will be array of objects.
So, in JS you need to read it through loop.

In current case you can try data[0].name it will work.

Comment: @JonathanNewton jQuery should already be parsing any JSON that is returned

Comment: @JayBlanchard was curious removed original comment

Comment: @Naincy I've tryed, and it returns "Undefined" :S.

Comment: can u share console.log(data);
and see my answer change typo of dataType from datatype. JS is caseSensitive.

Comment: @Erluan could you `console.log(data)` the output and attach it to your question?

Comment: It's in the first paragraph of the question @JonathanNewton

Comment: @JayBlanchard I'm not sure OP put the exact result see: "it returns the object like" also [see](https://jsfiddle.net/wvto6953/)

Comment: Fair enough @JonathanNewton.

Comment: @JayBlanchard also worth looking at the correct answer my initial comment was try and convert the string into JSON this would have brought OP to the correct answer sooner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Returning JSON from a PHP Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4064444/returning-json-from-a-php-script)

Your php script needs the correct header:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

It seems JQuery is intrepteing the result as the string {"id":"1","name":"Erluan"}, by having the correct header it should then be parsed as JSON.

Comment: Also on your ajax request it should be "dataType" not "datatype", changing this would of also fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried evaluating the ajax response? 
If not then try to call eval function and then fetch the values.

```
 success: function(data, string, jqXHR){
               var res = eval('(' + data+ ')');
                alert(res.name);
           }
```